# What is Reverse SSL? And how to do Reverse SSL?

Tags: ssl, terminology, reverse

My client ask me to do reverse ssl on his website. But i'm new on this term. Can anyone help me about this.

Please describe or refer how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

> In the case of secure websites, the SSL encryption is sometimes not
>   performed by the web server itself, but is instead offloaded to a
>   reverse proxy that may be equipped with SSL acceleration hardware.

"Doing" reverse SSL means choosing a system/server and configuring it. You should start by asking your client whether they already have a reverse proxy in place or if one needs to be set up.

So setting up reverse SSL (like standard SSL) should not impact your web site's design, the backing code and data store etc. It is [Transport Level Security (TLS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) and might actually be outside the bounds of the contract with your client.

Answer (score 0):

One use case would be running Apache Tomcat *behind* an Apache Web Server which handles SSL and acts as reverse proxy. Your client should specify more specifically.